# Autolayout Pin view from right of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've pinned my scroll view to top-left-right-bottom in IB,it's working fine.

I want's to do right pin my UIView loaded from nib in scroll view.

But it is not working.

Added my view to scrollview,

> When I add my views to UIView it works fine, but not working in ScrollView.
>   Here is my code.

```
   var constY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circularView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.IBscrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.IBscrollView.addConstraint(constY)

        var constW = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circularView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: screenWidth/2.5)
        circularView?.addConstraint(constW)
        //view.addConstraint(constW) also works

        var constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circularView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: screenWidth/2.5)
        circularView?.addConstraint(constH)

        var rightPin = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[myView]-40-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dCircularViews)
        self.IBscrollView.addConstraints(rightPin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of first constraint try the following:

```
var leadingConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: circularView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.IBscrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
self.IBscrollView.addConstraint(leadingConst)
```

You may keep all other constraints same.

Comment: No Bro, it's not working for me.I think there is some problem using scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'isn't working' but when you say pin, does that mean you don't want the view to move when `IBscrollView` is scrolled? In which case I would recommend looking at this documentation:
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html

If you want the scroll view to scroll and it isn't - when using Autolayout and `UIScrollView` you have to make sure there are `NSLayoutConstraint`s, from views inside the `UIScrollView`, connected to the top and bottom of the `UIScrollView` so it can set its `contentSize` correctly. Which is talked about here: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add UIView inside scrollView with name contentView after setting auto layout constraints in all directions. Add auto layout for contentView inside viewDidLoad method. Use contentView as base to add other items such as labels and buttons. Set their auto layout constrains related to contentView. Objective c code for this

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              relatedBy:0
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];

    NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                               relatedBy:0
                                                                  toItem:self.view
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0];
   [self.view addConstraint:rightConstraint];
  }
```

Check this tutorial for complete guide:http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/